# FastAPI - Python - overrides dependencies

Tags: python, fastapi

Is it possible to override dependencies like this in FastAPI?

[image: override dependencies]

I need to overide it from APIRouter

Comment: Don't register the  `dependencies` on the API router if they shouldn't be present on a route - use two routers in that case, one for authenticated routes (with the dependencies) and one for unauthenticated routes (without the dependencies); you can then mount/include them inside the same parent router. It also reads better with `unauthenticated_router.post` or `public_router.post` as it becomes clearer what the routes are getting registered under.

Comment: @MatsLindh techically this will modify the dependencies for this router right ?

Comment: You'll have two routers with different dependencies, one that has a dependency that requires a valid user and one that don't; you then register the endpoints to the router that have the behavior you want. It's very apparent what you're doing if you're registering an endpoint to `unauthenticated_router` compared to `authenticated_router`, instead of having to look for what dependencies are active for any given route in a hierarchy. So there is not really any "this" router; it's split into two different routers with different behaviors.